# Emacs failing to save encrypted file

Tags: gpg, encryption, pgp

I've used Emacs' built-in gpg support to encrypt/decrypt files for years. A few days ago, I tried to save an ecrypted file that had changes and the save wouldn't finish. The minibuffer shows "Saving file ..." but doesn't save.

Emacs doesn't hang (I'm able to quit the process with C-g), but nothing happens. I don't see any errors reported in *Messages*.

I created a new test file, encrypted it with epa-encrypt-file, decrypted it, then changed it and tried to save - same result, the save doesn't complete.

- Emacs 28.2 (9.0) from https://emacsformacosx.com/
- MacOS Ventura 13.4.1 on Apple M1

I'm not certain these are relevant, but these are found on my system (installed via Homebrew):

- gpg (GnuPG) 2.4.3
- libgcrypt 1.10.2

Comment: similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76388376/400544

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue is now fixed with the latest gnupg 2.4.4 (I upgraded and am able to encrypt `.org.gpg` files)
https://dev.gnupg.org/T6481

Answer (score 14):

Downgrade to GnuPG 2.4.0 should help.

There is an issue registered in gnupg and numerous reports in other resources:
https://dev.gnupg.org/T6481

It is still not fixed as of GnuPG 2.4.3, unfortunately.

Comment: Homebrew doesn't have a formula for 2.4.0 so I downgraded to 2.2.41. I'm sure that's not ideal, but at least it works. Thank you so much @maxim-kim!

Comment: @vortek you can use this script: https://gist.github.com/sankalp-khare/94fee1727ec5d199018be225127510d2 like `./switch-gnupg.sh 2.4.0` to change to version 2.4.0 in your homebrew setup. It will also pin that version so that subsequent brew upgrade won't get you back to the latest.

Comment: For those on mac having this issue...


Uninstall new gpg: `brew uninstall gnupg`


Install old gpg: `brew install gnupg@2.2`

Symlink so that Emacs finds it: `ln -s  /opt/homebrew/opt/gnupg@2.2/bin/gpg /opt/homebrew/bin/`

Answer (score 5):

If downgrading gnupg is not an option one can also set this in the Emacs config:

```
(fset 'epg-wait-for-status 'ignore) ; this is dangerous see below
```

After that Emacs is able to write the `*.gpg` file just fine (see my edit below for caveats!).

Source: https://www.masteringemacs.org/article/keeping-secrets-in-emacs-gnupg-auth-sources

### Edit

As mentioned in the comments, while the proposed solution above works, it is not recommended as it may incur in data loss (though it hasn't happened to me it is something you need to be aware of). The proper solution (for now) is to use a custom build of GPG 2.4.1 with gniibe's patch applied https://dev.gnupg.org/rG2f872fa68c6576724b9dabee9fb0844266f55d0d.

Comment: This seems to work... except that it doesn't. As it says in the last comment of the [masteringemacs.org](https://www.masteringemacs.org/article/keeping-secrets-in-emacs-gnupg-auth-sources).

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @dvdgc13 I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since the fix for Emacs+EasyPG does not seem guaranteed, I am using a custom formula from my personal Homebrew tap with a version that I know works:

```
brew tap pgpbpadilla/pgpb 
brew install gnupg@2.2.41
```

More details at: https://github.com/pgpbpadilla/homebrew-pgpb

Original post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77629200/400544